# Listview adapter setting ImageButton background resource to wrong item on recycle

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewholder

When creating my adapter I pass along multiple parameters, one being a "1" or "0" based on whether or not a particular post was liked. When the ListView is first populated via the adapter, the ImageButton background resource is correctly set based on whether the favorites variable is a 0 or a 1. When the user scrolls down and then back up, however, the wrong listview item is populated, often times duplicating.

I will include some images as reference:

[ListView when first loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bcdq.png)

[ListView after scrolling to bottom and back up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiWbx.png)

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<postFeedPopulator>{
public TestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<postFeedPopulator> posts){
    super(context, R.layout.listview_postfeedfragment, posts);
}

View customView;
ViewHolder holder;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View customView, ViewGroup parent){
    final postFeedPopulator post = getItem(position);
    if(customView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_postfeedfragment, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.favoriteButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.favoriteButton);

        customView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) customView.getTag();
        //holder.favoriteButton.setTag("0");
    }

    if (post.favorited.equals("0")){
        holder.favoriteButton.setTag("0");
    } else if(post.favorited.equals("1")){
        holder.favoriteButton.setTag("1");
        holder.favoriteButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_2);
    }

    return customView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    ImageButton favoriteButton;
}
```

}

I have looked far and low to find a solution to this problem but I haven't been able to find one. I am new new Android and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the two images you posted are identical.

Comment: You're right. I have edited the post with the correct two images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the ImageButton background resource to the initial state (unclicked), in this case favorite_1, when the customView has already been inflated. The if/else statement will re-change the background resource if needed. Such a simple solution but it took me writing it out on here to figure it out.

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<postFeedPopulator>{
public TestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<postFeedPopulator> posts){
    super(context, R.layout.listview_postfeedfragment, posts);
}

View customView;
ViewHolder holder;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View customView, ViewGroup parent){
    final postFeedPopulator post = getItem(position);
    if(customView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_postfeedfragment, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.favoriteButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.favoriteButton);

        customView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) customView.getTag();
        holder.favoriteButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_1);
        //holder.favoriteButton.setTag("0");
    }

    if (post.favorited.equals("0")){
        holder.favoriteButton.setTag("0");
    } else if(qlustr.favorited.equals("1")){
        holder.favoriteButton.setTag("1");
        holder.favoriteButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_2);
    }

    return customView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    ImageButton favoriteButton;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please cover case when post.favorited different both 1 and 0

```
if (post.favorited.equals("0")){
    holder.favoriteButton.setTag("0");
    holder.favoriteButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_1);
} else if(post.favorited.equals("1")){
    holder.favoriteButton.setTag("1");
    holder.favoriteButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_2);
} else {
    holder.favoriteButton.setTag(" ? ")
    holder.favoriteButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_2);
}
```

Comment: The way the ListView is populated it will never equal something other than 0 or 1 but I will implement this check anyway. The initial problem still persists. The ImageButton background resource is being set to the wrong listview item.

Comment: Also with each if, you must set background resource for button. Are you try this?